# Date value is stored as 0000-00-00 in DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am trying to store values from a Datepicker in my MySQL DB with php Laravel.

The request works AFAIK, since when I dd the request the date is displayed, but when looking into the database I only see "0000-00-00" and not the date, so I guess something is lost with my controller but I don't know what.

Here is my Controller method:

```
public function storePost(Request $request) {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'titel' => 'required|max:255',
            'standort' => 'required|max:255',
            'kontakt' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'startdatum' => 'required|date',
            'enddatum' => 'required|date',
            'beschreibung' => 'required|',
        ]);

        $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'titel' => $request->titel,
            'standort' => $request->standort,
            'kontakt' => $request->kontakt,
            'startdatum' => $request->startdatum,
            'enddatum' => $request->enddatum,
            'beschreibung' => $request->beschreibung,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

I already tried it with this version after seeing it on stack overflow, but it didn't work either:

```
public function storePost(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'titel' => 'required|max:255',
            'standort' => 'required|max:255',
            'kontakt' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'startdatum' => 'required|date',
            'enddatum' => 'required|date',
            'beschreibung' => 'required',
        ]);

        $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'titel' => $request->titel,
            'standort' => $request->standort,
            'kontakt' => $request->kontakt,
            'startdatum' => Carbon::parse($request->startdatum),
            'enddatum' => Carbon::parse($request->enddatum),
            'beschreibung' => $request->beschreibung,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

I am not sure if it is relevant, but here is the snippet of the html code where the date is coming from:

```
            <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                <div class="w-full px-3">
                    <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="startdatum">
                        Startdatum
                    </label>
                    <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                    py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                    focus:border-gray-500 @error('startdatum') border-red-500 @enderror" id="startdatum" name="startdatum" type="date" placeholder="Startdatum">
                    @error('startdatum')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                <div class="w-full px-3">
                    <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2 text-base" for="enddatum">
                        Enddatum
                    </label>
                    <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded
                    py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white
                    focus:border-gray-500 @error('titel') border-red-500 @enderror" id="enddatum" name="enddatum" type="date" placeholder="Enddatum">
                    @error('enddatum')
                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What format is the date being returned to you in?

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's the format: 
"startdatum" => "2021-11-20"
      "enddatum" => "2021-11-24"

Comment: Pretty sure User is not part of the Request object

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got some more stuff like a title, location and email that is in the request, all of this gets stored correctly in the database, just the date is displayed as the 0's

Comment: WHat version of Laravel are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly laravel 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Post Model, make sure you have $fillable property with correct properties:

```
class Post extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['standort','titel','kontakt','startdatum','enddatum','beschreibung'];
....
}
```